# To display posts with a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i have create a custom post type, now i want display all the posts without the custom post type . I have display the custom post like this

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'badge',
    );
    // The query itself
    $sb_user_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The loop
    while ( $sb_user_query->have_posts() ) : $sb_user_query->the_post();
        $badge_id = $sb_user_query->post->ID;
        $badge_title = get_the_title();
        $author = get_the_author();
        $author_id = get_the_author_ID();
        $badge_image_small = get_the_post_thumbnail( $badge_id, array(16,16) );
        $post_data = get_post_meta( $badge_id, '_metabox', true );
        $comment_data = get_post_meta( $badge_id, '_comments', true );
        echo $author.$badge_image_small;
    endwhile;
```

now i want to display all the post type without the "badge" post type. How can i do this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think below code will give u the idea.

<?php
  $type = 'badge';
  $args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    global $post;
    $badge_id = $post->ID;
    $badge_title = get_the_title();
    $author = get_the_author();
    $author_id = get_the_author_ID();
    $badge_image_small = get_the_post_thumbnail( $badge_id, array(16,16) );
    $post_data = get_post_meta( $badge_id, '_metabox', true );
    $comment_data = get_post_meta( $badge_id, '_comments', true );
    echo $author.$badge_image_small;

endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```